# jscript long or double data type?

Tags: windows, types, numeric, jscript, wsh

I try to declare a variable having Double data type in WSH/Jscript like here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h139yks%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

```
var level : double = 5346.9009;
```

But on WinXP and win2003 (another OSes not tested) I see this error:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.6
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 1996-2001. All rights reserved.
c:\tmp\t.js(1, 11) Microsoft JScript compilation error: Expected ';'
```

Also I tried

```
var level = new Double();
```

this produces `Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Double' is undefined`

How should it be done properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad and good news.

First the bad ones. The documentation you are reading is for a "scripting engine" that is part of the NetFramework, not WSH. The WSH JScript documentation is here:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hbxc2t98(v=vs.84).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hbxc2t98%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

The good ones. The intrinsic numeric type of JavaScript in the WSH is the same as the double from JScript. More precisely, as the documentation states, it is an 8 bytes IEEE 754, and can hold values from ±1,7976931348623157x10<sup>308</sup>  to  ±5x10<sup>-324</sup>.

So, you only need to declare the variable and store inside it the required value:

```
var level = 5346.9009;
```